# A RenderFlex overflowed by 61 pixels on the bottom Inside a Single Child Scroll View

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen which I wanna insert some checkBoxes dynamically, but in this example I fixed three on it just to test. This is the code:

```dart
Expanded(
  flex: 3,
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: AppColorSecondary,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(i.description, textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          SizedBox(height: 3,),
          Text("Cod: ${i.code}", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          Divider(),
          Text("R\$ ${i.value.toString()}"),
          SingleChildScrollView( // the error is here
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("AA"),
                  value: true,
                ),
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("AA"),
                  value: true,
                ),
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("AA"),
                  value: true,
                ),
              ],
           ),
       ),],
        ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
))),
```

Running this, it throws this error:

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 61 pixels on the bottom.

I just wanna make it scrollable to be able to show all the checkboxes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the SingleChildScrollView with Expanded since it is inside a column so as to aquire the max space left in the column

```
Expanded(
 child:SingleChildScrollView(
  child:Column(
   children:[
     CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text("AA"),
      value: true,
     ),
     CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text("AA"),
      value: true,
     ),
     CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text("AA"),
      value: true,
     ),
   ]
  )
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are nesting `SingleChildScrollView` with `Column`

what you need to do is to give the `SingleChildScrollView` a parent container with fixed height

otherwise it should be placed in flex widget like `Expanded` or `flexible` which will gives it fixed height also behind the scene but depending on the other items in colmun/row

Comment: Which height I have to put if I don't know exactly?

Comment: I wrapped it on a container without a height and the error persists

Comment: height for the container .. the amount of height you wish your items to scroll in